# CSS issue moving up a section of a page

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

I have the following site I am working with and it is built on BigCommerce:

[My client's site](http://beautifulseeker.com)

I am trying to make the logo and slider move up, but want everything to flow like it is now (meaning the header stays as the last thing on the page).

When I change the #header to say

```
position: absolute;
```

it moves the logo and slider up, but the footer menu also slides up awkwardly and I am not well-versed enough in CSS to know to fix that. Anyone able to assist on this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide fiddle instead of the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello try this html structure 
note: "currency-converter"  this name div put in header section  and remove **clear:both**  from css - worked for me

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="currency-converter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I took this design over from another developer. Changing the structure worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to move your .currency-converter into your #Header, that would fix your problem I believe, then you could ignore position:absolute and leave it relative.